# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in android studio

Tags: android

i am trying to add module and but its gvien error like this:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.anghatechsolution.eww.datetimepicker.SlidingTabStrip" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.anghatechsolution.eww.datetimepicker-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]

can any one having idea about this.

Comment: Please add relevant code and other details which will be useful to understand the issue

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: actuly am trying to add module its working fine in sample code but after adding in main project its given error like that.

Comment: can anyone having idea ?

Answer (score 0):

This error means, that you are trying to access class, that currently doesn't exist.

Try to check the name of class, you accessing

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: @NileshRathod unfortunatelly, i can't comment (49 reputation of 50), so i posted probable solution as an answer

Comment: please delete this ans

Comment: in example project its working fine but after ading moudule in the main app its given error.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by setting the name attribute to your class like this:

```
[Activity(Name = "somepackage.custombuttonrenderer")]
public class CustomButtonRenderer: ButtonRenderer
{ }
```

An explanation is in my answer here: [Why is my custom ButtonRenderer not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47838449/why-is-my-custom-buttonrenderer-not-working/48400421#48400421)